# Parallel Programming in Java: Is the Multithreading in Java is Really Parallal?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am implementing a multi-threading program (parallelism) in java in order to reduce the time. This is my code-

```
public class Slavethread1 implements Runnable {

    int permut[][][];
    double w;
    double y;
    int benchmark;

    public Slavethread1(int[][][] permut, double w,double y, int benchmark){
        this.permut = permut;
        this.w = w;
        this.y= y;
        this.benchmark=benchmark;
    }

    public void run() {
        // the program1 is to treat the matrix permut
          permut=program1. Traitement((permut, w, teta, benchmark);
    }

    public int [][][] getMatrix() {
        return this.permut;
    }
}
```

The master thread code-

```
public class Monthread1 implements Runnable {

    int[][][] permut;
    int benchmark;
    double w; 
    double y;
    Map<Object, int [][][]> Setmatrix=new HashMap<Object, int [][][]>();

    public Monthread1( Map<Object, int [][][]>Setmatrix,double w, double y, int benchmark) {
        this.permut = permut;

        this.benchmark=benchmark;
        this.w=w;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int ii=0; ii< 1000;ii++){

            for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Slavethread1 mth1 = new Slavethread1 (pemut,,w,y,benchmark);
                Slavethread2 mth2 = new Slavethread2 (permut, w,y,benchmark);
                SLSthread3 mth3 = new SLSthread3 (permut,, w,y,benchmark);
                Slavethread4 mth5 = new Slavethread4(permut,w,y,benchmark);

                Thread thead1 = new Thread(mth1);
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(mth2);
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(mth3);
                Thread thread4 = new Thread(mth4);

                thead1.start();
                thead2.start();
                thead3.start();
                thead4.start();

                try {
                    thead1.join();
                    thead2.join();
                    thead3.join();
                    thead4.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

                //put the output of the previous slaves in the map Setmatrix
                Setmatrix.put(1, mth1.getMatrix());
                Setmatrix.put(2, mth2.getMatrix());
                Setmatrix.put(3, mth3.getMatrix());
                Setmatrix.put(4, mth4.getMatrix());

                // bestMtrixInPOPULA to shoose the best matrix from Setmatrix
                permut=MthodsNeedForThreds. bestMtrixInPOPULA(Setmatrix,benchmark);
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }


            System.out.println(" NOW i AM HERE ");
            // the SLaveGLL to traite the result again 

            SLaveGLL mth6 = new SLaveGLL (permut, w,y,benchmark);
            Thread thrSLAllNehg = new Thread(mth6);
            thrSLAllNehg.start();

            try {
                thrSLAllNehg.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //put the results again to the map in order to treat it again
            Setmatrix.put(1, permut);
            Setmatrix.put(2, permut);
            Setmatrix.put(3, permut);
            Setmatrix.put(4, permut);
        }      

    }

    public Map<Object, int [][][]> getMatrix() {
        return this.permut;
    }
}
```

But I did 'not find any difference in term of time running between sequential program and parallel program. Therefore, I thought that- may be implementing multi-threading program doesn’t mean the real parallelism programming.

So, please any explication about the parallelism by multi-threading in java? Or if it’s real parallelism or concurrent programing. And what could I do to spin my program to real parallel program in order to reduce my time running.

Comment: No, I call them the same time I must join them (thread.start), and I notice in the console that they were running in concurrent @ Elliott Frisch

Comment: No, I call them at the same time (thread.start) , and I notice in the console that they were running in concurrent @ Elliott Frisch

Comment: please provide your SlaveThread classes

Comment: Have a look at this : call your methods synchronized https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm

Comment: there are no common resource (variables) between my threads, therefore, I would implement them at the same time @user7185318

Comment: My threads are simple sequential programs(functions) all whate i need that -running all my threads then returning their results to the Master thread ...scheduls.put(1, mth2.getMatrix());

Comment: Keep in mind that starting and joining a thread takes some overhead. If the task that thread is given isn't big enough, that overhead could overwhelm the multithreading benefits.

Comment: But I must be sure that all the threads have finished in order to take their results (the output), furthermore, I noticed from the counsel that all the threads were running in concurrent @yshavit

Comment: Your code is nearly unreadable. Indentation is random​, variable names are gobbledygook, and some variables' definitions aren't shown (`thead2`, ...). Why are you starting threads from a `Runnable`? How many cores does your machine have? What else is running besides your program? What are the types you haven't shared? Where's your timing code, and why all the expensive extraneous calls inside the timed  method? I suspect your methodology is incorrect and yields meaningless results. What _are_ your results? Mean? Standard deviation? Anything?

Comment: @ Lew Bloch I just edited my pseudo code of Slavethread1 
And Monthread1(the master thread), the thread is a simple programme its input is a matrix and the output is a matrix  also, and in the master thread I wait intel finishing the running of all the threads then take the best solution among them to treated again using the thread SLaveGLL, as what I mentioned I used Intel Core i5

Comment: @M.amani : In your code are a couple of syntax errors, I assume you have fixed them, else it wont compile. And, you have only 2 kernels, but you can have 4 threads, but that means, you can only run 2 threads at the same time

Comment: @ user7185318 what do you mean by  2 kernels and why I can implement just 2 threads at the same time

Comment: and what  are my mistakes

Comment: Everything that your "slave" threads do happens in the method called `Traitement`.  Where is the code for that method?  You can't expect anybody to tell you what the threads do wrong, if you don't show anybody what the threads _do_.

Comment: Your `Monthread1.run()` routine loops three thousand times, creating and destroying four threads each time through the loop.  It would be *MUCH* more effective to have just four threads that each do three thousand things than to have twelve thousand threads that each do just one thing.

Comment: The code in your examples does not compile.  The only time you should post code that does not compile is when your question is, "why does this code not compile?"  Otherwise, you run the risk of making people think that you are too lazy to do your own work.

Comment: @ james large No, I cannot let each thread run 300 iterations.   
The conception of my algorithm oblige me to create a thread at each iteration then send its results to the master in order to treat it again.